# How insert static block all CMS page sidebar left sidebar Magento 2.x?

Tags: magento2

I want insert static  block  all cmd page  sidebar left sidebar  magento 2.x

Step1:
I create a static block that i want to add to a specific CMS page which   name static-block-1 .

ex.

```
<div class=”element-blue”>
        <h3>Static Block 1</h3>
        <p>This is display on left sidebar on cms page</p>
</div>
```

Setp2:

How Can I display on CMS Page Left Sidebar??

Comment: <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('static-block-1')->toHtml();?> work for me may be help someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to display the static block on all cms pages with 2-columns-layout:**

create a new file in your theme:

```
<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view.xml
```

and add your static-block to the sidebar.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="mycustomstaticblock">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_block_id</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Keep in mind that the CMS-page needs to be set to 2-columns.

---

**EDIT: REMOVED IN VERSION 2.3.4 but still possible in prior versions - If you want to display your static block on a specific cms page:**

Navigate to to your CMS-Page:

```
Content -> Pages -> Your CMS-Page
```

go to "Design"

add following code to "Layout Update XML"

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
     <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="mycustomstaticblock">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_block_id</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Take a look at the new documentation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-layouts for Magento versions 2.3.4 or above as mentioned by @Luis Paulo Lohmann

Comment: thanks  , i want to  display the static block on all cms pages with 2-columns-layout, Plz can details file name with path. 1. create a new file in your theme: name with extention & full Path. 2. add your static-block to the sidebar file name & path

Comment: you have to create the cms_page_view.xml file in your custom theme as mentioned above. There you have to insert the code which I wrote. Replace "static_block_id" with the identifier which you chose for your static block

Comment: Magento_Cms not found in my theme, can i create this directory or copy from base thme (use porto theme)?

Comment: work for me Magento_Theme/

Comment: Please notice that Magento 2.3.4 removed the option to add custom layout updates via admin. Here's the new documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-layouts